# How are programs like Photoshop rendered?

Tags: user-interface, graphics, multiplatform

Just a quick question about the structure of common commercial editing software such as Photoshop or Sony Vegas:

While I know how the UI of these applications is implemented, I'm not clear on how other more advanced graphics are developed?

I'm well aware of libraries such as OpenGL and DirectX for 2D and 3D rendering. I'm also aware that much can be done using software rendering (Integrated Graphics). But which option do these programs use?

I know Photoshop has an option for GPU accelerated rendering. This means that they must have written the rendering code two times, one for software rendering, and another for rendering with the GPU. This isn't even taking into account the fact that it is generally better to use DirectX on Windows machines, while OpenGL is compatible with other operating systems.

Do developers of these applications really take the time to re-write the graphics code for all of these possibilities, or is there some library / easier conversion that is used?

Thanks!

Comment: Photoshop uses OS integrated UI, usually optimized depending on hardware availability. GPU acceleration option is for Image processing, which is strongly speed up by gpu parallel computing.

Comment: Software rendering and integrated graphics chips are *not* the same thing. Not even close.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how Photoshop and Vegas do it; But where I work we have developed several OS independent imaging applications. There are frameworks that claim to be system independent for aiding in drawing graphics, Qt, Firemonkey are two I've used. But these are a big hassle since you still have to include code or compiler directives everywhere to distinguish between which OS your running on. There are only a few drawing primitives that every graphics application has in common.

For 2D applications, if you can draw lines, then your can also draw curves with your own library. If you can fill polygons, than you can also fill curves. Furthermore, if you can draw lines and fill polygons, then you can also draw in 3D. Since there is such a small set of these primatives, you can create your own graphics context object (OOP) that can do all these functions. That graphics context can (like you said) switch between using DirectX, GDI, OpenGL, Metal, Vulkan or your own Software Renderer.

For each OS, you'll have to figure out how to get a handle on the window object and it's buffer to draw on. You'll also have to figure out how to link that buffer to your graphics card if applicable.

The only place where this method of creating your own graphics context doesn't work so well is when it comes to certain graphics card features like AA or how Shaders are programmed. Because of the extra work I've never tried to program these features myself. This is why in 3D programs, like Maya, 3d Studio Max, Blender ect, the viewport always looks better if it's not set to software rendering.  Most graphics programmers love to rely on their graphics API's.

**So in Summary:**

If you can draw lines, fill polys, and have access to pixel data in a OS agnostic way, than you can do 80% of graphics programming on your own. These functions can be encapsulated into your own library that can draw these primatives differently on different systems.